# ImageMagick; PHP, equivalent to shell "convert"

Tags: php, imagemagick, gif, animated-gif, imagemagick-convert

In my web hosting, I can't use shell, so is there any alternative for this command?

```
system("convert $src +dither -layers optimize -depth 16 -colors 32 $dest");
```

I want to compress gif files, so I need to preserve animation.

P.S:

Of course, that I first tried to do it by my own. But without success. So i wrote this question.

Example:

```
$im = new Imagick("first.gif");
$im->optimizeImageLayers();
$im->writeImages("phpmodul.gif", true);

system("convert first.gif -layers optimize shell.gif");
```

- first.gif - 649 kB
- phpmodul.gif - 647 kB
- shell.gif - 347 kB

Any help?

P.P.S:

I solved this. My solution.

```
$animation = new Imagick("$file");
foreach ($animation as $frame) {
  $frame->quantizeImage(32, imagick::COLORSPACE_RGB, 16, FALSE, TRUE); 
}
$animation = $animation->optimizeImageLayers();
$animation->writeImages("$file", true);
```

Comment: Have you tried anything or do we have to come up with all the code?

Comment: How about reading [here - php imagemagick extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.imagick.php).

Comment: @Jack I add my example code :)